# python subprocess SVN update FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, svn, subprocess

Below is a piece of python code that is causing an error. Can someone help with a solution who might have ran into this issue before?

````
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call("svn update C:/folder1/subfoler1/ --non-interactive -q")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "D:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1112, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified```

I have gone through various other posts on similar issue but nothing related to svn update call. I haven't tried adding shell=True as this wasn't the best solution as suggested by many in this forum that it might be a security issue.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: I did not have SVN command line tools installed on the system. The sub-process couldn't call the SVN commands.